# Fully qualified source filepath showing in release candidate Assertion failure

Tags: c++, windows, assertions, rapidjson, c++17

I have a problem currently with a shipped version of our software. Under certain conditions an assertion is thrown which looks like the following...

[image]

This error message is embarrassing enough, but the sugar topping is that fact that some how there is a fully qualified reference of the source file that raises the exception... including my name!
Obviously this was the location of that source during development, but this is a release candidate (for deployment) so I was under the assumption that no debug/symbols would be built into the binaries?

I tried looking through the various properties of the projects, but cannot deduce any option that may cause 'persisting' of fully qualified source filepaths in release builds. Is this a by product of an assertion being
triggered in a release build, or have I missed something here. If this is standard behavior, how do others mitigate this issue for assertions (i.e ensure that a fully qualified path does not include any 'un-professional'
strings if presented to the user).

P.S The assertion in this case is failed by rapidjson, which is a perfectly valid issue being raised here.

Comment: Assertions don't typically trigger unless you built a debug version by accident

Comment: @AndyG That was my understanding, however rapidjson is a header only library. I guess some flag is allowing assertions to be included into the compliation units associated with those headers?

Comment: Can you try to `#define NDEBUG` in your code before any includes?

Comment: @AndyG Thank you, that has stopped those assertions. Should I encapsulate this #define NDEBUG within #ifndef _DEBUG directives? I'm using VS2017 and would still like to know about assertions during debug builds? Many thanks, please feel free to add this as an aswer :)

Comment: That's strange, I thought that VS automatically defined "NDEBUG" for release configurations. You can look under project properties > C/C++ > Command Line to see if "NDEBUG" is there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the symbol `NDEBUG` is not defined, otherwise assertions wouldn't be raised at all.

You can define them explicitly in code as `#define NDEBUG` before any includes, or you could do it on the command line.

VS would be Project Properties > C/C++ > Command Line, and you'd type `\D "NDEBUG"` for your release config (but not debug configuration).

gcc you'd do `-d NDEBUG`

clang you'd do `-D NDEBUG`

Comment: Thank you this has fixed my problem. NDEBUG was not defined by default for some reason, I have manually added them to the command line for releases.